# SML - Iterate through String

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'm trying to find if sentences read from a file has some pattern.

So far, I've written the code that reads all the sentences from file line by line, and puts those sentences to an array.

```
val infile = "c:/input.txt" ;

fun readlist (infile : string) =
    let val ins = TextIO.openIn infile 
        fun loop ins = case TextIO.inputLine ins of 
                            SOME line => line :: loop ins 
                          | NONE      => [] 
    in loop ins before TextIO.closeIn ins 
    end;

val pureGraph =  readlist(infile);
```

Comment: Tried to find some information on SML but couldn't understand...

Answer (score 2):

Try to write a function that evaluates to `true` if the letter `a` is in a string. Use [explode](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/smlnj/basis/string.html#SIG:STRING.explode:VAL) to get a list of Chars. Recurse or fold over that list until you find `a` or reach the end. When you have that function, generalize it to any character. This will probably lead you to an `O(n^2)` runtime complexity.

Another approach is to sort the character list, remove duplicates, zip it with the correct list of characters and compare each tuple with recursion/fold. This should run in `O(n log n)` time because of the sort.

A third approach is to fold over the character list with an array or a hash map. In the array or map you add in what the current character is. At the end you see if all characters were found. This approach should run in `O(n)` time if your hashmap is constant-time.

Comment: Oh I should try the function 'explode'. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show me the way to use explode for iterating through the Chars in String?

Comment: You could count the number of vowels like this: `foldl (fn (c, n) => if isVowel c then n+1 else n) 0 (explode s)`

Comment: SML/NJ has a hash table implementation (I think it is an extension rather than part of the standard basis library): http://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/hash-table.html

Answer (score 2):

Divide and conquer your problem:

1. Write a function `isPanagram : string -> bool` that determines this for a single line.

   One strategy could be: Start with the set of all letters. Loop through the string, and for each character in the string, remove it from the set until the end of the string, or the set is empty. If the set is empty, it is a panagram. This requires that you represent sets in some way, e.g. with a list or a binary search tree.

   Consider looping through the string by index, rather than exploding it:

   ```
   val allLetters = ...
   fun remove x ... = ...
   fun isEmpty ... = ...

   fun isPanagram s =
       let val len = size s
           fun loop i missingLetters =
               isEmpty missingLetters orelse
               i < len andalso loop (i+1) (remove (String.sub (s, i)) missingLetters)
       in loop 0 allLetters end
   ```
2. Write a function `readLines : string -> string list` that reads the content of a file and separates the lines into elements of a list:

   ```
   fun isLinebreak c = c = #"\r" orelse c = #"\n"
   fun readLines filename =
       let val ins = TextIO.openIn filename
           val data = TextIO.inputAll ins
           val _ = TextIO.closeIn ins
       in String.tokens isLinebreak data end
   ```

   (Yes, reading the file one line at a time will save memory.)

Answer (score 2):

The SML/NJ library has a number of data structures which can be used for things like sets and hash tables. They are not exactly well-documented, but [this](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/riccardo/prog-smlnj/notes-011001.pdf) explains a bit how to use them. Using their set library, you can write something like this:

```
structure CharSet = RedBlackSetFn(struct
    type ord_key = char
    val compare = Char.compare
    end)

val alphabet = CharSet.fromList (explode "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");

fun isPanagram s = 
    let val chars = CharSet.fromList (map Char.toUpper (explode s))
        val letters = CharSet.intersection (chars,alphabet)
    in CharSet.numItems letters = 26
end;
```

used like this:

```
- isPanagram "We promptly judged antique ivory buckles for the next prize.";
val it = true : bool
- isPanagram "We promptly judged antique plastic buckles for the next prize.";
val it = false : bool
```